# ReSharper type member layout ordering and [DataMember] attributes

Tags: c#, resharper

I would like to define standard WCF data contracts using the `[DataMember]` attributes. I also want to specify the `Order` property.  When performing an auto format, ReSharper re-orders my properties so they're not longer in the order specified in the `[DataMember]` attribute.

Now this has no effect on the compiled code, but it does make it annoying.

Is there a way to make ReSharper's type member layout respect the ordering I define in the attributes?

```
public class MyDataContract
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int One { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int Two { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public int Three { get; set; }
}
```

Now since One,Two,Three are not in alphabetical order, the default sort is to make it One,Three,Two.  Is there any way to change this?  I'm aware of the type member layout's ability to notice attributes, but was unable to find a way to gather data from within the attribute and use that in sorting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, ReSharper's default is to not reorder properties, so the example you give doesn't get reordered. However, it does sort fields by name, which might be what you're encountering.

Fortunately, it is possible to edit the order using the Options dialog. But, as far as I can see, you need to specify a class attribute in order to match the rules being applied. In this case, your class can have the `[DataContract]` attribute, which makes it all nice and easy.

ReSharper 9 has a nice shiny new visual editor to define the layout and ordering: Code Editing → C# → File Layout. You can take a look at the COM interop rules to see how they're handled to ignore ordering for COM structs (basically, match the COM attributes and have no rules).

ReSharper 8 makes you edit a scary XML file, in a slightly different options page: Code Editing → C# → Type Members Layout. Select "Custom layout" and scroll down until you find the section with a comment "Do not reorder COM interfaces…". You want to make a new `Pattern` element that looks something like:

```
<Pattern>
  <Match>
    <And>
      <Kind Is="class"/>
      <HasAttribute CLRName="System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute"/>
    </And>
  </Match>
</Pattern>
```

This pattern will match a class with the `[DataContract]` attribute, but specifies no rules, so won't reorder properties, or fields.

Comment: so this completely works as advertised, thanks!  This is perfect for telling ReSharper to not reorder members within a [DataContract], thanks!